# Second Rviz instance doesn't show robot model from ROS master

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am running a ROS master on a first PC with a Universal Robot in it. In a second PC I'd just like to see the visualization with Rviz. After exporting the IP address of the master using

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=myipadress
```

The second PC connects to the first one, but I am having trouble to see the robot in the second PC. After adding the robot model in second PC I just get errors in the robot model. It is just shown in a weird position and is coloured white.
[Link to screenshot](https://ibb.co/fD1LjF)
[image: image description]

*Sorry for the screenshot picture with my phone, but the PC is right now not connected to the internet anymore, so I couldn't post from there. Image upload native here in ROS answers is not yet available for me. Sorry again.*

Did I forget an important step before connectiong or what went wrong here?

Edit/Update:

```
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=""   
ROS_DISTRO="indigo"   
ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros"   
ROS_MASTER_URI="160.69.69.100"   
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks"   
ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270541/second-rviz-instance-doesn%27t-show-robot-model-from-ros-master/) by [matl](https://answers.ros.org/users/29014/matl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-09**:
@matl: please attach the screenshot to your question directly. I've given you enough karma for that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-09**:
Please update your question with the values of `ROS_IP`, `ROS_HOSTNAME` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` for *each of the involved computers*. A simple diagram showing your network layout and configuration would also help.

Most likely you don't have a working DNS, and should set `ROS_IP` on all hosts.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-10**:
Without the other requested information we cannot help you.

**Comment by [Marq](https://answers.ros.org/users/26396/marq/) on 2017-09-11**:
My best guess is that the second machine does not know where to look for the models of the robot you are trying to load.

On the second PC do you have the Universal Robot package installed or are you using it from source?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-11**:
The second machine can't subscribe to the `/tf` topic properly, that is most likely the problem. The 'white' meshes and 'bunched up' view are typical symptoms of that. that's why there is a request for the `ROS_IP`, `ROS_HOSTNAME` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` on all involved hosts.

**Comment by [matl](https://answers.ros.org/users/29014/matl/) on 2017-09-14**:
I updated the values above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like @gvdhoorn said in the comments to your question, your second machine can't find the transforms. You have set `ROS_MASTER_URI` incorrectly. If you look at the [ROS Network Setup page on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup), you'll see that `ROS_MASTER_URI` needs to include the port number and you should set your `ROS_HOSTNAME` environment variable too:

```
$ export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

You should set these along with `ROS_IP` on each machine that you're using. `ROS_IP` should be set to the IP of the machine itself.

Now, the value of `localhost` means that everything will only be run locally so you should change that to be your master's IP address. It would look like

```
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://160.69.69.100:11311
```

Use `ROS_HOSTNAME` if you're using a hostname

```
$ export ROS_HOSTNAME=<your-hostname>
```

or `ROS_IP` if you're using an IP address

```
$ export ROS_IP=<your-ip>
```

Where `<your-hostname>` and `<your-ip>` is your machine's hostname and IP address, respectively.

Check out the [environment variables page on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matl](https://answers.ros.org/users/29014/matl/) on 2017-09-14**:
Hey,
I tried it again, but anyways I get the same error:

> declare -x ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=""
> declare -x ROS_DISTRO="indigo"
> declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros"
> declare -x ROS_HOSTNAME="160.69.69.100"
> declare -x ROS_IP="160.69.69.102"

**Comment by [matl](https://answers.ros.org/users/29014/matl/) on 2017-09-14**:\

> declare -x ROS_MASTER_URI="http://160.69.69.100:11311"
> declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks"
> declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros"

**Comment by [matl](https://answers.ros.org/users/29014/matl/) on 2017-10-14**:
Do you have any ideas, what else I could try or what I have to change?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-14**:
Your *Fixed Frame* is set to `map`. Does that frame exist? If not, change it to a frame that does exist.